# How to get the Install & Testing Note of a Task or Defect Item

Tags: c#, axosoft

I'm developing a win forms application using AxosoftAPI.NET. I've implemented functionality to search for Items like Tasks, Defects, Incidents and Projects.

I can also check whether an Item has attachments. Now I need to know how to check if an Item (Task or Defect) has an Install or Testing Note attached to it. I searched in Axosoft's developers website but couldn't find anything helpful. How can I achieve this in C# using AxosoftAPI.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and Testing Notes are not standard fields in Axosoft so are most likely Custom Fields that were added by your team.  All custom fields should be returned when getting items, however large text fields, are only returned when getting a single item, rather then getting lists of items.

From the developer.axosoft.com page regarding the GET multiple and specifying the columns parameter :

(comma seperated string) Containins the names of the columns to return for each item. Defaults to all columns. However, please note that for performance reasons long text fields (such as 'Description') are not returned by this API call. To get the values of long text fields, use the GET /defects/{id} call to retrieve a single item.